# How to get duplicate strings of list with indices in Python

Tags: python, string, list, indexing

I do realize this has already been addressed here (e.g., [Removing duplicates in the lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-the-lists)), [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops/522578#522578), [Append indices to duplicate strings in Python efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430884/append-indices-to-duplicate-strings-in-python-efficiently) and many more...... Nevertheless, I hope this question was different.

Pretty much I need to write a program that checks if a list has any duplicates and if it does, returns the duplicate element along with the indices.

The sample list `sample_list`

```
sample = """An article is any member of a class of dedicated words that are used with noun phrases to
mark the identifiability of the referents of the noun phrases. The category of articles constitutes a
part of speech. In English, both "the" and "a" are articles, which combine with a noun to form a noun
phrase."""

sample_list = sample.split()
```

```
my_list = [x.lower() for x in sample_list]

len(my_list)
```

```
output: 55
```

The common approach to get a unique collection of items is to use a set, set will help here to remove duplicates.

```
unique_list = list(set(my_list))
len(unique_list)
```

```
output: 38
```

This is what I have tried but honestly, I don't know what to do next...

```
from functools import partial

def list_duplicates_of(seq,item):
    start_at = -1
    locs = []
    while True:
        try:
            loc = seq.index(item,start_at+1)
        except ValueError:
            break
        else:
            locs.append(loc)
            start_at = loc
    return locs

dups_in_source = partial(list_duplicates_of, my_list)

for i in my_list:
    print(i, dups_in_source(i))
```

This returns all the elements with indices and duplicate indices

```
an [0]
article [1]
.
.
.
form [51]
a [6, 33, 48, 52]
noun [15, 26, 49, 53]
phrase. [54]
```

Here I want to return only duplicate elements along with their indices like below

```
of [5, 8, 21, 24, 30, 35]
a [6, 33, 48, 52]
are [12, 43]
with [14, 47]
.
.
.
noun [15, 26, 49, 53]
```

Comment: You might want to first remove from `sample` anything that isn't an alpha or space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along these lines:

```
from collections import defaultdict

indeces = defaultdict(list)

for i, w in enumerate(my_list):
    indeces[w].append(i)

for k, v in indeces.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print(k, v)

of [5, 8, 21, 24, 30, 35]
a [6, 33, 48, 52]
are [12, 43]
with [14, 47]
noun [15, 26, 49, 53]
to [17, 50]
the [19, 22, 25, 28]
```

This uses `collections.defaultdict` and `enumerate` to efficiently collect the indeces of each word. Ridding this of duplicates remains a simple conditional comprehension or loop with an if statement.

Comment: Nah, `sample_list` and `my_list` only differ in case sensitivity.

Comment: @SayandipDutta My bad updated the desired output now.